# Spotify SDK throwing AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNKNOWN_ERROR on trying to open the login activity

Tags: android, spotify

I am using the following Spotify sdks:
- auth: 1.1.0
- app-remote: 0.6.3

And running my app on:
- Android 10

and when I try to login on Spotify through my app using the following piece of code

```
val request = AuthenticationRequest.Builder(
    SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    AuthenticationResponse.Type.CODE,
    SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI
)
    .setScopes(SPOTIFY_SCOPES)
    .build()

AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(
    activity,
    CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE,
    request
)
```

it fails, the login activity is automatically closed after very few seconds and the following error is thrown:

> E/Spotify: [OkHttp https://accounts.spotify.com/...] AccountsPrefligtRequest failed with status code: 400
>   E/Spotify: [main] AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNKNOWN_ERROR

But, when I execute that piece of code twice "quickly", the login activity is opened successfully.

Is there any Spotify SDK bug that I am unaware of? 
Is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out what was causing the problem. It was the scope `"user-read-birthdate"` that I was using.

Looking for it on the web, I encountered [that link](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1262) that says that that scope was removed.